# Twitter login callback is failing when orientation of the device changes

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, twitter, twitter-oauth

In unity, if I click twitter login it's opening a login dialog of Twitter. At this instant, if I change the orientation of the device then after authorizing, the call back I'm getting is login failed. Can anyone suggest some few ideas to work around this issue?

I already tried to freeze the app orientation when the user clicks twitter login button but unity app is freezing its orientation but the twitter web view dialog doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in activity
`@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }`